# Can not pass the data from input to a div using REDUX

Tags: reactjs, redux

I created the next code which take the value from an input and should display it in a `div` element.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {createStore} from "redux";
import {connect, Provider} from "react-redux";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const initalstate = {
    firstName: 'F',
    lastName: 'L'
};

const F_NAME = "F_NAME";
const L_NAME = "L_NAME";

const changeFirstName = (newFirstName) => {
    console.log(newFirstName);
    return {
        type: F_NAME,
        payload: newFirstName
    }
};
const changeLastName = (newLastName) => {
    console.log(newLastName);

    return {
        type: L_NAME,
        payload: newLastName
    }
};
const rootreducer = (state = initalstate, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case F_NAME:
            return {
                ...state, firstName: action.payload
            };
        case L_NAME:
            return {
                ...state, lastName: action.payload
            };
    }
    return state
};
const store = createStore(rootreducer);

function App(props) {
    const dispatch = props.dispatch;
    // console.log(props);

    return (
        <div className="test">
            <div className='test'>
                <input type="text" onChange={(e) => {
                    dispatch(changeFirstName(e.target.value))
                }} value={props.changeFirstName} placeholder="first name"/>
                <input type="text" onChange={(e) => {
                    dispatch(changeLastName(e.target.value))
                }} value={props.changeLastName} placeholder="last name"/>
            </div>
            <div>{props.changeFirstName}</div>
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        firstName: state.firstName,
        lastName: state.lastName
    }
};

const Wrapp = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Wrapp/>
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I can see the `onChange` function using console log. I mean, i can see the text from my inputs if i use `console.log()`, but when i tried to display the input value in `<div>{props.changeFirstName}</div>`, i didn't see anything. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are passing the wrong values to those inputs.
It should be

```
<input type="text" onChange={(e) => {
      dispatch(changeFirstName(e.target.value))
      }} value={props.firstName} placeholder="first name"/>
<input type="text" onChange={(e) => {
      dispatch(changeLastName(e.target.value))
      }} value={props.lastName} placeholder="last name"/>
```